# Cannot see foreign key constraints on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Bit rusty on the sql side as I have not touched in a while

I have added a foreign key constraint using the Diagram and clearly says that there is a fk relationship.

However when scripting the table or viewing the keys in SQL Server explorer I cannot see the grey key.

Am I missing something?
Not sure I am doing it correctly.

How do you create one programatically between 2 tables? Should it appear in the Explorer under keys?

Thanks a lot for any input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the FK relationship, use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ChildTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ChildTable_ParentTable
  FOREIGN KEY (FK column in child table)
  REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(column in parent table)
```

and possibly define what happens on UPDATE or DELETE of the primary key in the parent table:

```
  ON DELETE ...... (CASCADE, NO ACTION, SET NULL)
  ON UPDATE ...... (CASCADE, NO ACTION, SET NULL)
```

You should be able to query the data dictionary views to check if that FK constraint is really in there:

```
SELECT
    fk.NAME,
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Child table',
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'Parent table',
    fk.*
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
```

This will list all existing foreign keys in your current database.

Comment: Hi,
Just seen your post.Thanks a lot for your time.Querying the relationships they are there however still not showing in Explorer
mmmm Missing something??

Comment: @devnet247: not sure - do you have any filtering going by any chance?? Are you sure you're looking at the same server/database?? Or are you querying on your local machine, but Explorer shows you your dev server? (has happened to me before.....)

Answer (score 7):

The foreign keys in the designer are in memory until they are saved. Look for a open design tab that hasn't been saved. Save it and refresh the database. The foreign keys should show up.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to save what you changed and refresh the Object Explorer. For my case, I can see the grey key icon for my foreign key in both Columns and Keys folders. However, I can't see it is my Constraints folder. Apparently, it is considered normal?